# Mysqli DELETE QUERY not working in PHP Script

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Im using the following code to remove an entry from a table what i want to do is to check if any value was deleted from the table.If one value is deleted,the script should print success else false.This is what i have achieved till now.Please help

```
<?PHP
    $mysqli = new mysqli("SQLHOST.COM","CLIENT","PASSWORD", "DNAME", 1234);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {

    printf("cONN Sucees");


    if ($result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM ktable WHERE code='value'")) {
        printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);


     printf($result->num_rows);
        $result->close();
    }

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

what you delete what you need to return is `affected_rows` http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

What you need to Replace

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM ktable WHERE code='value'")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);


    printf($result->num_rows);
    $result->close();
}
```

Working Code

```
$value = ""; // Set To any Value
$mysqli = new mysqli ( "SQLHOST.COM", "CLIENT", "PASSWORD", "DNAME", 1234 );
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf ( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error );
    exit ();
} else {
    printf ( "cONN Sucees" );
    if ($mysqli->query (sprintf ( "DELETE FROM ktable WHERE code='%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string ( $mysqli, $value ) ) )) {
        printf ( "Affected Rows  %d rows.\n", $mysqli->affected_rows );
    }
}
```

You should have a working output